# Rails4 - ambiguous column name and no such column error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my controller to list the users.

```
@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

I tried to change the order using the following

```
@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
```

I got the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#index
SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: created_at: SELECT DISTINCT "users"."id" FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_languages" ON "user_languages"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (user_languages.level_id = 1) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Then I changed the line as follows

```
@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('user.created_at DESC')
```

and I am getting the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#index
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.created_at: SELECT DISTINCT "users"."id" FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_languages" ON "user_languages"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (user_languages.level_id = 1) ORDER BY user.created_at DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Kindly help to resolve this error.

Comment: you have typo: user**s**.created_at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have some default scope on `User` that joins `user_languages`, and there is `created_at` column in both of these tables. So you should point out on which table's `created_at` you want to order:

```
@user = User.paginate(page: params[:page]).order('users.created_at DESC')
```